# Show Gtk::FileChooserDialog without a parent window

Tags: c++, gtk, freeglut

I'm writing an application with an OpenGL GUI. On Windows, I'm using `GetOpenFilename` to allow the user to select a file.

I tried to implement similar functionality for on Linux for Gtk, using `Gtk::FileChooserDialog` (following [this tutorial](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.0/sec-dialogs-filechooserdialog.html.en)). I'm trying to keep the function signature the same for Windows and Linux, so I modified the example to look like this:

```
std::string browseFile( std::string filetypes )
{
    Gtk::Main kit(false);

    Gtk::FileChooserDialog dialog( "Please choose a file",
            Gtk::FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN );
//    dialog.set_transient_for( kit.instance() );

    //Add response buttons the the dialog:
    dialog.add_button( Gtk::Stock::CANCEL, Gtk::RESPONSE_CANCEL );
    dialog.add_button( Gtk::Stock::OPEN, Gtk::RESPONSE_OK );

    //Add filters, so that only certain file types can be selected:
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::FileFilter> filter_any = Gtk::FileFilter::create();
    filter_any->set_name( "Any files" );
    filter_any->add_pattern( "*" );
    dialog.add_filter( filter_any );

    //Show the dialog and wait for a user response:
    int result = dialog.run();

    //Handle the response:
    switch( result )
    {
        case( Gtk::RESPONSE_OK ):
        {
            std::cout << "Open clicked." << std::endl;

            //Notice that this is a std::string, not a Glib::ustring.
            std::string filename = dialog.get_filename(  );
            std::cout << "File selected: " <<  filename << std::endl;
            return filename;
        }
        case( Gtk::RESPONSE_CANCEL ): { std::cout << "Cancel clicked." << std::endl; break; }
        default: { std::cout << "Unexpected button clicked." << std::endl; break; }
    }
    return std::string( "" );
}
```

The main difference is that I eliminated the `set_transient_for` bit, since my main window isn't managed by Gtk (it's created by freeglut).

**Problem**: after I choose a file, the dialog just freezes. My application continues running, I can process the selected file, it's just the dialogs that freeze.

**How do I kill the dialog box after choosing a file ?** I tried `dialog.hide()`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm also trying to contain Gtk-specific code to this function, keeping `int main()` free of platform-specific code.

Comment: Just a wild guess, since I have no idea if and how can freeglut interfere with gtk on a platform, but maybe it's some kind of threading issue? In case you use separate threads, have you tried creating an unified message loop in a single thread?

Comment: @Ivarpoiss, I don't think that's possible; event processing with freeglut is done by registering callbacks for specific message types (keyboard, mouse etc) - you don't have access to the message loop directly.

Comment: According to the documentation, both APIs provide a function to run a single iteration of event processing loop. Event handling and callbacks will work same way as before. Other option is dropping freeglut and doing all the window managing with GTK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to create overloaded class for this.  The code is below:

```
    class FileChooser : public Gtk::FileChooserDialog {
public:

    static std::string getFileName() {
        FileChooser dialog("Select file", Gtk::FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN);
        kit.run(dialog);
        std::string ret = dialog.chosenFile;
        return ret;
    }
protected:
    static Gtk::Main kit;
    std::string chosenFile;

    FileChooser(const Glib::ustring& title, Gtk::FileChooserAction action = Gtk::FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN) :
    Gtk::FileChooserDialog(title, action) {
        chosenFile = std::string("");
        add_button(Gtk::Stock::CANCEL, Gtk::RESPONSE_CANCEL);
        add_button(Gtk::Stock::OPEN, Gtk::RESPONSE_OK);
        signal_response().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
                &FileChooser::on_my_response));
    }

    void on_my_response(int response_id) {
        chosenFile = get_filename();
        hide();
    }
};
Gtk::Main FileChooser::kit(false);
```

You can use it like this:

```
std::cout << "File: " << FileChooser::getFileName() << "\n";
```